# Ruby debug is stepping into rather than stepping over

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-debug

I am writing a Rails 4 application in Ruby 2, and I am using the `debugger` gem to debug my code.

Here is the situation currently:

I place a `debugger` statement in my Rspec tests, run the tests in the shell, and the program breaks as expected. Wishing to step to the next line, I enter `n`, but the debugger actually steps *into* the code, showing me the inner workings of libraries I don't care to see.

**So the issue is, the debugger command `n` is acting like `s`.**

How can I solve this problem*?

*I am not willing to put a breakpoint on the next line and then `continue`, that will get very old, very fast.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Debugger does not yet fully support Ruby 2.0](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/47), and one of the issues is that [next incorrectly acts like step](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/47#issuecomment-15607423). You’ll have to wait till the issue is fixed for it to work correctly, or use an alternative debugger such as [Byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug).

Comment: Yep, that's it. I'll just use `byebug` in the meantime. Thank you for the issue page link.